# Trimming a vertical line

Tags: math-mode

I'm a new user here and was wondering if it is possible to trim a vertical line in a way similar to trimming `\cmidrule`. I would like to apply it to the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\[
\arraycolsep=0.1mm
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrr}
 & x^5 && &-& 3x^3 & +& 2x^2&-&x &+&1\\
-&x^5& +& x^4&-& 2x^3\\
\cmidrule(l{3mm}r){1-6}
&&&x^4&-&5x^3&+&2x^2&-&x&+&1\\
&&-&x^4&+&x^3&-&2x^2\\
\cmidrule{4-8}
&&&&-&4x^3&&&-&x&+&1\\
&&&&&4x^3&-&4x^2&+&8x\\
\cmidrule{6-10}
&&&&&&-&4x^2&+&7x&+&1\\
&&&&&&&4x^2&-&4x&+&8\\
\cmidrule{8-12}
&&&&&&&&&3x&+&9
\end{array}
\]
\end{minipage}
\hspace{-8mm} 
\vrule height -5mm
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\textwidth} 
\[
\arraycolsep=0.1mm
\begin{array}{llllllll}
& x^2 & - & x & + & 2\\
\cmidrule(l{-0.75mm}){1-8}
& x^3 & + & x^2 & - & 4x & - & 4\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

which looks like in the picture below:

[image]

But I would like to have it as shown in the next snapshot:

[image]

This was done using Adobe framemaker.

All tips & tricks are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure whether this suits your needs. The code is a tad cleaner, but still very messy due to the requirement of alignment by operator *and* operand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
  \begin{array}{*{5}{r>{{}}c<{{}}}r<{\quad}>{\quad}l*{4}{>{{}}c<{{}}r}}
   x^5 & &     &-& 3x^3 &+& 2x^2 &-& x &+& \multicolumn{1}{r<{\quad}|}{1} &&&          & & x^2 &-&  x &+& 2 \\ \cline{12-20}
  -x^5 &+& x^4 &-& 2x^3 & &      & &   & & \multicolumn{1}{r<{\quad}|}{1} &&& \quad x^3 &+& x^2 &-& 4x &-& 4 \\ \cline{1-5}

       & & x^4 &-& 5x^3 &+& 2x^2 &-& x &+& 1 \\
       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{-x^4} &+& x^3 &-& 2x^2 \\ \cline{3-7}

       & & & \multicolumn{2}{r}{-4x^3} & &  &-& x &+& 1 \\
       & & & & 4x^3 &-& 4x^2 &+& 8x \\ \cline{5-9}

       & & & &      & \multicolumn{2}{r}{-4x^2} &+& 7x &+& 1 \\
       & & & &      & & 4x^2 &-& 4x &+& 8 \\ \cline{7-11}

       & & & &      & &      & & 3x &+& 9
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```